# Can't stop memory leaks

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I'm new to programming and i'm currently trying to write a program that can mimic the du command using multiple threads. My program works well but i'm having some memory leaks that i'm not too sure on how to fix.

This is the function i'm having trouble with:

```
void addSubdirectories(const char *basePath) {
    linkedlist *stack = linkedlist_empty();
    if (stack == NULL) {
        return; // Exit function if memory allocation fails
    }

    searching((char *)basePath, &dir_lock);
    linkedlist_insert(linkedlist_first(stack), strdup(basePath)); // Insert base path into the list

    while (!linkedlist_isEmpty(stack)) {
        char *currentDir = strdup(linkedlist_inspect(linkedlist_first(stack)));
        if (currentDir == NULL) {
            break; // Exit loop if memory allocation fails
        }
        
        linkedlist_remove(linkedlist_first(stack));
        DIR *dir = opendir(currentDir);        
        if (dir == NULL) {
            free(currentDir);
            continue;
        }

        struct dirent *entry;
        while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
                if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0) {
                    char subDirPath[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];
                    snprintf(subDirPath, sizeof(subDirPath), "%s/%s", currentDir, entry->d_name);
                    // Add subdirectory to the list for traversal
                    searching(subDirPath, &dir_lock);
                    linkedlist_insert(linkedlist_first(stack), strdup(subDirPath)); // Insert subdirectory into the stack
                }
            }
        }
        closedir(dir);
        free(currentDir); // Free memory for currentDir after removing from the list
    }
    
    linkedlist_free(stack);
}
```

I've been using valgrind so i know where the leak is, but all my attempts at freeing the memory fails

```
10,982 bytes in 500 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 10 of 10
at 0x48407B4: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
by 0x49227F9: strdup (strdup.c:42)
by 0x10A25B: addSubdirectories (.c:329)
by 0x109734: main (.c:28)
```

I feel like there is something obvious i'm missing, can someone please help me out, any help would be super appreciated!

Edit: This is the linkedlist i'm using to allocate space https://pastebin.com/Qz3zF7A7

Comment: When you delete the nodes, do you remember to free the memory allocated by `strdup`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If you look at the `linkedList_free()` function in the linked pastebin, it does `free(n->next->value)`.

Comment: Where is line 329? Where do you free that memory? Consider a [mcve].

Comment: @MarkAdler There's actually two `free(currentDir);`.

Answer (score 1):

`linkedList_insert()` has its own call to `strdup()`:

```
    newNode->value = strdup((char*)v); // Using strdup to duplicate the string
```

So you don't need to call `strdup()` when calling it. Since you never free your own duplicates, they become memory leaks.